# Share a bool variable / NSNUmber between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers and I want to share a bool variable between them.
So I create a bool variable with a @propery (nonatomic, assign) on both sides and on the one side I wrote

```
newVC.myBool1 = self.myBool2;
```

On the other view controller I can read the value of the passed bool variable, but I need to change it at the second view controller so I can read the value at the first view controller.
So I know, this is not possible, because `bool* it is a primitive type.

So I used `NSNumber`, but this also does not work. On the first view controller I set on `viewDidLoad`

```
self.myBool1 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
```

On the second view controller:

```
self.myBool2 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

But on the first view controller the value is 0 - NO... So it seems that creating the new `NSNumber` is not shared to the first view controller.

What can I do to solve this problem?
Regards Tim

Comment: @property(nonatomic, readwrite) for bool

Comment: I changed this on both view controllers, but it does not work. I think it pass the bool parameter as value not as reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of choices, but which you should use depends on whether both viewControllers need notification of when the value changes.

If you don't need notification, the easiest choice is to use a global `BOOL` variable, although purists will scoff at the suggestion. But really it's two lines of code and you're done. Another option would be to store the value in `NSUserDefaults`.

If you need change notification in each viewController, perhaps the cleanest design is to write a "set" method in one viewController that sets the value in both itself and the other viewController. Something like:

```
-(void) setMyBool:(BOOL)newValue
{
  myBool = newValue;
  otherViewController.myBool = newValue;
}
```

If you want to change the value from either viewController, it gets a little trickier because you have to have each viewController keep a reference to the other and make sure not to recurse when setting the value. Something like:

```
-(void) setMyBool:(BOOL)newValue
{
  if ( self.busyFlag == YES )
     return;
  self.busyFlag = YES;
  myBool = newValue;
  otherViewController.myBool = newValue;
  self.busyFlag = NO;
}
```

Yet another option would be to use `NSNotifications` to change the value and have each viewController class listen for the change notification. And TheEye's suggestion of writing a wrapper class and keeping a reference to an instance of that class in both viewControllers would work too.

If you don't need change notifications, though, I would just create a global `BOOL` variable and get on with the rest of the application because it's so easy, reliable and hard to mess up.

Comment: Sure if it makes you happy. You have to be careful that the BOOL that is pointed to doesn't go away while either viewController is alive, which is why I think a global is somewhat safer.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSNumber` object is immutable, so you can't use it like that. If you write `[NSNumber initWithxxx]`, in fact you create a new object.

If you want to share a `number` or `boolean` between several classes, you should create your own wrapper class with setters and getters for the bool value (or subclass `NSNumber`). This class you can share between classes.

Comment: Are there any other simple solutions?

Comment: It doesn't get any simpler - you need a mutable object to share. Depending on what you want to do with the shared variable other solutions might be better suited (like a value management object or singleton), but not simpler.